# Visual Studio C# Web API Shutting Down Immediately After Starting

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

Recently we upgraded our Citrix desktops from 2012 to 2016. In the process of re-installing my applications I decided to install Visual Studio 2019 instead of sticking with 2017.

I am currently building a .NET Core Web API and after moving to the new server and upgrading Visual Studio I said why not push to Core 2.2. Everything seemed to be running smoothly for a while.

After a few application start/stops while debugging, I would start with debugging, it looks like it's loading the app, then I get this in my output;

"The thread 0x1468 has exited with code 0 (0x0)."

I never had this issue with the other machine or version of VS. I been searching all over and have tried...

- Repairing Visual Studio 2019
- Reinstalling Visual Studio 2019
- Reinstalling .NET
- Cleaning my solution
- Rebuilding

The only thing that seems to work is restarting my machine which is getting annoying while I am trying to work on something. Not sure if there is an IIS Express process that is maybe stuck running, or something with VS 2019. Any tips on debugging this would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I am not sure if posting any code would be helpful, as the code still works fine on VS 2017 on the old machine. Also I don't seem to be having any issues running other programs, but they're also not targeting .NET Core 2.2.

Comment: Even if you have a problem with your code, questions seeking help with programing related problems, are out of scope at Super User.  You don't mention what build of Visual Studio 2019 you have installed.